# PHP echo easy problem ;)

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

Ok, it's Wordpress related and I know about Wordpress Stack Exchange, but I'm asking here because this is mostly a PHP question.

I want my code to display something or nothing using if statement.

The problem is I'm going to have a variable and bloginfo('template_directory') in-bulit function.

I wrote this:

```
    <?php if (!empty($instance['example'])) 

    echo "<li><a href=". $example ."><img src="?><?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?><?php echo "/images/example.png /></a></li>"; ?>
```

It works fine until $instance['example'] is not empty, when is - it still displays the template directory link including images/example.png.

Any ideas?

I've tried " . bloginfo('template_directory') . " but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show the actual generated HTML and what is wrong with it?

Comment: try encapsulating the echo in { and }

Comment: Every answer has missed one thing(that though maybe not technically required), that i always make an effort to add, and that's quotes on HTML attributes. Each answer has concatenated but failed to include additional quotes around the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php if (!empty($instance['example'])) 

    echo "<li><a href=". $example ."><img src=".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/images/example.png /></a></li>";
?>
```

Comment: Exactly, there was no need for braces and I knew it, just didn't know how to do that. By they way I've done it almost the same way as you and it didn't work. I guess made a typo. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's because "bloginfo" function "echoes" itself, but get_bloginfo doesn't. It's useful for other functions too, like the_title X get_title and others..

Answer (score 2):

PHP if statements that do not have braces { } will only evaluate the first line thereafter. To resolve this,

```
 <?php if (!empty($instance['example']))  {

echo "<li><a href=". $example ."><img src="?><?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?><?php echo "/images/example.png /></a></li>"; } ?>
```

Try that and see if it works for your needs. All I did was insert the braces so that your if statement spans all of your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the `:` after the if statement to make an `if endif;` block. Alternatively use the standard curly brackets to enclose all your commands in the if statement.

Currently it's only checking `if` for the *first* `echo` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php if (!empty($instance['example'])) {

    echo "<li><a href=". $example ."><img src="?><?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>
    <?php echo "/images/example.png /></a></li>"; 

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use.

```
<?php 
if( !empty( $instance['example'] ) )
    echo '<li><a href="' . $example . '"><img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/example.png" alt="" border="0" /></a></li>'; 
?>
```

First we add those missing attribute quotes.
Second we use the stylesheet path to ensure it points to the correct location for a child theme.
Third we call `get_bloginfo` to get a return value for the echo statement.
Fourth, i also added a `border="0"` to the image, borders aren't usually wanted for an image inside a link and also added an alt tag, because it will at least help pass HTML validation, even if you leave it empty.

Answer (score -1):

Same answer as others, but with better formatted code:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($instance['example']))
{
    echo '<li><a href=' . $example . '><img src=' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/example.png /></a></li>'; 
}
?>
```

Added brackets, removed unnecessary opening/closing php tags, and converted strings to single quotes since there are no variables or special characters contained within them that need processing.